# SSRS Highlight Duplicate Values in Column Across Entire Report

Tags: sql-server, vba, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS report that looks at products used in a bill of materials. It lists the items involved, the bill of materials (BOM) they belong to and other various information. I would like to highlight ANY duplicates in the item column without having to sort by item.

Example data:

| Level | Item No. | BOM No. | Quantity Per |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001468 | 017998 | 4 |
| 1 | 001850 | 017998 | 6 |
| 1 | 017663 | 017998 | 2 |
| 1 | 017792 | 017998 | 2 |
| 2 | 001468 | 017663 | 3 |

So in the above data, the item # "001468" should get highlighted even though the information in the other columns is different per row.

- I am aware of the "Previous" function but I don't want to re-order the item number column so I don't think using that is an option
- The report sorts by level so that it first lists all the items in the top level (level 1) followed by the lower levels (2, 3, 4 etc...)
- There can be multiple duplicates (not just 2), so any solution will have to factor that in
- Would like the duplicate(s) too be highlighted in Bold Red

If more information is needed please let me know.

**Edit: More Details added below 08/05/2022**

Here is the code I am working with which begins with a recursive CTE:

```
WITH CTERBOM AS  
(
    SELECT PBL.[Production BOM No_], PBL.[Version Code], PBL.[No_], PBL.[Quantity per], 1 AS LVL
    FROM [DataBaseName$Production BOM Line] PBL
    LEFT JOIN [DataBaseName$Production BOM Header Extra] PBHEX ON PBHEX.[No_] = PBL.[Production BOM No_]
    WHERE PBL.[Production BOM No_] = '008722' AND PBHEX.[Active Version No_] = PBL.[Version Code]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT PBL2.[Production BOM No_], PBL2.[Version Code], PBL2.[No_], PBL2.[Quantity per], LVL + 1
    FROM [DataBaseName$Production BOM Line] PBL2
    INNER JOIN CTERBOM ON CTERBOM.[No_] = PBL2.[Production BOM No_]
)

SELECT
CTERBOM.[LVL]                           AS [Level],
CTERBOM.[No_]                           AS [Item No.],
CTERBOM.[Production BOM No_]                    AS [Production BOM No.],
CTERBOM.[Quantity per]                      AS [Qty. Per]



FROM CTERBOM
LEFT JOIN [DataBaseName$Production BOM Header Extra] PBHEX ON PBHEX.[No_] = CTERBOM.[Production BOM No_]

GROUP BY
CTERBOM.[LVL],
CTERBOM.[Production BOM No_],
CTERBOM.[No_],
CTERBOM.[Quantity per],

ORDER BY
CTERBOM.[LVL],
CTERBOM.[Production BOM No_],
CTERBOM.[No_]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to do add a new column to the query, as `duplicates = count(*) over (partition by [Item No.])` (insert your actual column name).

Then use that to conditionally highlight the Item No field in the report if the value of the duplicates column is > 1. You would do this by going to the Item No field in the report > properties > fill > fill color > press the expression button and enter something like:

`=IIf(Fields!duplicates.Value > 1,"Yellow","Default")`

Add this column to your final select:

```sql
-- APPROACH 1:

SELECT
CTERBOM.[LVL]                              AS [Level],
CTERBOM.[No_]                              AS [Item No.],
count(*) over (partition by CTERBOM.[No_]) as duplicates,
/* ... */

/* APPROACH 2:
if you can't use approach 1 because of other code not currently 
shown in the question, you can wrap the entire select in 
another select, which will always work:
*/

WITH CTERBOM AS  
(
    SELECT PBL.[Production BOM No_], PBL.[Version Code], PBL.[No_], PBL.[Quantity per], 1 AS LVL
    FROM [DataBaseName$Production BOM Line] PBL
    LEFT JOIN [DataBaseName$Production BOM Header Extra] PBHEX ON PBHEX.[No_] = PBL.[Production BOM No_]
    WHERE PBL.[Production BOM No_] = '008722' AND PBHEX.[Active Version No_] = PBL.[Version Code]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT PBL2.[Production BOM No_], PBL2.[Version Code], PBL2.[No_], PBL2.[Quantity per], LVL + 1
    FROM [DataBaseName$Production BOM Line] PBL2
    INNER JOIN CTERBOM ON CTERBOM.[No_] = PBL2.[Production BOM No_]
)

select  level,
        [Item No.],
        count(*) over (partition by [Item No.]) as duplicates,
        [Production BOM No.],
        [Qty. Per]
from    (
           SELECT
           CTERBOM.[LVL]                      AS [Level],
           CTERBOM.[No_]                      AS [Item No.],
           CTERBOM.[Production BOM No_]       AS [Production BOM No.],
           CTERBOM.[Quantity per]             AS [Qty. Per]
           /* rest of existing query ... */
        ) t;
```

Comment: I have added my code now. I am not sure where and what exactly to add what you've suggested but please let me know steps I should take. Just need to know specifically how to alter the SQL script.

Comment: @adhocEY I have edited my answer to show where to put the extra column. I have included two possible approaches. The second will always work, the first is neater but may not work as expected if there is additional code in your query not shown in the question.

Comment: Approach #1 worked great, thank you so much for your help in solving this issue!

Comment: If I wanted to ONLY show the results where the Duplicates were greater than 1 what would be my best approach?

Comment: In that case I would change the query in SQL. But you can't use a window function in a where clause (ie, you can't say `where count(*) over ... > 1`, so instead you have to use a subquery that does the main query including the `count(*) over ...` column, then in the outer query add the predicate `where duplicates > 1`.